# How to remove the last comma in comma separated prime numbers within a range?

Tags: c, loops, primes

I have the code for finding prime numbers within a range.

The problem is to remove the last comma.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b,i,x,c,f=1;
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    for(x=a;x<=b;(x++,f=0))
    {

        for(i=2;i<x;i++)
        {
            if(x%i==0)
            {
                 f=1;
            }
        }

        if(f==0)
            printf("%d,",x);
     }
  }
```

But the output contains an extra comma in the last.
For example

> 2,3,5,7,

whereas the expected output is

> 2,3,5,7

Comment: Just do not print it? Then there'd be no need to remove it.

Comment: Print `"2"` (or whichever is first), then print `",%d"` for each following prime.

Comment: That's the desired output.

Comment: @Yunnosch That's when we are checking from 2-10.

Comment: @Yunnosch what if we need to check from 20-30 ?We cant print 20.

Comment: Why not? Just print the first one you find without a comma, all others after a comma.

Comment: Of course, if the numbers weren't prime, it would be a totally different problem.

Comment: @juanchopanza Do I detect a trace of sarcasm there?

Comment: Are you interested in improving efficiency/spedd, too? If yes, check the `;i<x;`. No answer has yet improved that double waste and an upvoted answer will probably not happen while that is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b,i,x,c,f=1;
    char backspace = 8;

    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    for(x=a;x<=b;(x++,f=0))
    {

        for(i=2;i<x;i++)
        {
            if(x%i==0)
            {
                 f=1;
            }

        }
        if(f==0)
           printf("%d,",x);
     }
     printf("\b"); // or printf("%c", backspace);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of flag you can decide directly what you want to print between numbers

And note that you can break out of the internal loop as soon as f is set to 1

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b,i,x,c,f=1;
    const char* delim = "";
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    for(x=a; x<=b; (x++,f=0))
    {
        for(i=2; i<x; i++)
        {
            if(x%i==0)
            {
                f=1;
                break; //no need to continue the checking
            }
        }

        if(f==0) {
            printf("%s%d",delim,x);
            delim = ", ";
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another flag, just a simple counter that tells you if you are printing the first time then check the flag to decide what to print, e.g.

```
#include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int a,b,i,x,c,first=0,f=1;
        scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
        for(x=a;x<=b;(x++,f=0))
        {

            for(i=2;i<x;i++)
            {
                if(x%i==0)
                {
                     f=1;
                }
            }

            if(f==0)
                {
                    if(first==0){
                        printf("%d",x);
                    }else{
                        printf(",%d",x);
                    } 
                    first++
                }
         }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a flag to detect the first occurrence of `printf()` and print the first number as such without any `,`. For consecutive number printing precede with `,`

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b,i,x,c,f=1,flag=0;//Flag to mark first occurrence
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    for(x=a;x<=b;(x++,f=0))
    {

        for(i=2;i<x;i++)
        {
            if(x%i==0)
            {
                 f=1;
                 break;// Once the condition fails can break of the for loop as it fails for the prime number condition at the first case itself
            }

        }
            if(f==0)
            {
            if(flag==0)
            {//Check if it is first time
                printf("%d",x);
                flag = 1;//If so print without ',' and set the flag
            }
            else
                printf(",%d",x);// On next consecutive prints it prints using ','
            }
        }
  }
```

This method also avoids the `,` when only one number is printed.

Eg: When input is 2 and 4. It prints just `3` and not `3,`

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need odd number best practice for minimum loop is given below;

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b,i,x,c,f=1;
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b); 

    while (a < b) 
    {
        if ( (a%2) == 1) {
           printf("%d", a);
           if ( (a + 1) < b && (a + 2) < b)
               printf(",");
        }
        a = a + 1;
    } 
}
```

please check from the site
http://rextester.com/MWNVE38245

Answer (score 0):

Store the result into a buffer and when done print the buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define RESULT_MAX (42)

size_t get_primes(int * result, size_t result_size, int a, int b)
{
    int i, x, f = 1;
    size_t result_index = 0;

    if (NULL == result) || (0 == result_size) || ((size_t) -1 == result_size))
    {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return (size_t) -1;
    }

    for (x = a; x <= b; (x++, f = 0))
    {
        for (i = 2; i < x; i++)
        {
            if (x % i == 0)
            {
                 f = 1;
                 break;
            }
        }

        if (f == 0)
        {
            result[result_index] = x;
            ++result_index;
            if (result_size <= result_index)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Result buffer full. Aborting ...\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return result_index;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    int result[RESULT_MAX];

    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);

    {
        size_t result_index = get_primes(result, RESULT_MAX, a, b);

        if ((size_t) -1 == result_index)
        {
            perror("get_primes() failed");
        }
        else if (0 == result_index)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "No primes found.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d", result[0]);

            for (size_t i = 1; i < result_index; ++i)
            {
                printf(", %d", result[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This example uses a simple fixed-size buffer, if this does not suite your needs replace it by a dynamic one.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a "language-agnostic" problem: "How do I output a comma-separated list without a final comma?"  It is not specifically about prime numbers.

You seem to be thinking of you list as a series of `[prime comma]` units.  It isn't.  A better way to think of it is as a single `prime` as the head of the list, followed by a tail of repeated `[comma prime]` units.

Some pseudocode to illustrate the general idea:

```
outputList(theList)
  separator = ", "
  output(theList.firstItem())
  while (theList.hasMoreItems())
    output(separator)
    output(theList.nextItem())
  endwhile
return
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*  this is just logic */

    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        k=0;
        for(j=2;j<=i/2;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
                k=1;
        }
        if(k==0)
        {
            c++;
            c++;
        }

    }

     System.out.println(c);
     for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
        {
            k=0;
            for(j=2;j<=i/2;j++)
            {
                if(i%j==0)
                    k=1;
            }
            if(k==0)
            {
                System.out.print(i);
                b++;
                if(b!=c-1)
                    {
                    System.out.print(",");
                    b++;
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//comma separated values


#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int Prime(int a, int n){
    bool prime[n+1];
    memset(prime,true,sizeof(prime));
    for(int p=2;p*p<=n;p++){
        if(prime[p]==true){
            for(int i=p*p ; i<=n; i+=p ){
                prime[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 2;i<= n;i++){
        if(i==2) cout<<i;    // here is the logic  first print 2 then for other numbers first print the comma then the values 
        else if(prime[i]) cout<<","<<i;
    }

}
int main(){
    int a =2 ;
     int n = 30; 
     Prime(a , n);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, n, count;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i=2; i<n; i++) 
    {
        count=0;
        for(j=2; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0) 
             count++;
        }
        if(count==1)
          printf("%d," i);

    }
    printf("\b \b");        
}
```

**\b is a nondestructive backspace. It moves the cursor backward, but doesn't erase what's there, it replaces it. For a a destructive backspace, 
use "\b \b"  i.e. a backspace, a space, and another backspace.**

This Program prints all the prime number up to given number with comma separated

Comment: This is a C question. Not a C++ one.

Comment: Yeah but the logic remains same
Please just change the c++ keywords to c for your reference